# How do to massively alter primary keys to tables in sql server database

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

Is there any way to massively alter primary keys(uid) to  all tables with no primary keys in sql server database ? I have a lot of tables and most of them don not have primary keys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an identity field to the table

```
Alter Table TableName
Add TableId Integer Identity (1, 1)
```

Here is how to add the Primary Key

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_TableKeyName PRIMARY KEY (TableID)
```

To generate this script for each table in your database, you can use one of the following

- The view [Information_Schema.Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx)
- Undocumented Stored Procedure [sp_MSforeachtable](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm)

Comment: I was looking a way to massively alter tables with primary key(PK), i have many tables and need to maintain them adding PK with single SQL script.

Comment: @shuxer: Answer edited to show you a way to do this for multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks Raj More for your useful hints